# Grep search certain characters any order any capitalization

Tags: regex, grep

I need to grep search for the characters "james".  The problem is they can be in any order and any of them can be capitalized.  For example the following would need to be found..

- *Aemjs*
- *emaJS*
- *SeMaJ*

That's just a few possibilities, obviously there are many more combinations.

If possible this needs to be done with one grep statement.  The grep search is being done with the software Encase and not on a unix machine.  The input only accepts one grep command.  Is it possible to do this in one statement?

Comment: Why do you need to do this, exactly?

Comment: The number of characters is way off - there are 5! = 120 ways to arrange the letters of the word james, so including the alternation operator and the parens a matching regex will require 5*120 + (120-1) + 2 = 721 characters, assuming case-insensitive matching can be configured. Write a short script in the programming language of your choice to print out the regex.

Comment: @collapsar: Thanks for pointing that out. I calculated all the possible combinations of `[a-z]{5}` (`24**5`). (Although it sounded impressive, I'm not sure why I did that. :()

Comment: Are you grepping a list of dictionary words, one per line? Or do you have to find these jumbled words as a substring within text?

Comment: I won't lie, this is for a homework.  We are given an image of a hard drive and there is an encrypted file which we know the password is "james" but in any order and any capitalization.  We also know the password is in plaintext somewhere else on the drive.  So my thought process was to think of a way to search for the character combination in other files in hope to find the original password.  This is all being done with EnCase.  So @Kaz this would be finding a substring within text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fun regex for you:

```
/ (?=.{0,4}j)(?=.{0,4}a)(?=.{0,4}m)(?=.{0,4}e)(?=.{0,4}s).{5} /i
```

What this'll do is look ahead to ensure that each character in the string "james" is matched within the next 5 characters, and the `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UxexNF/2)

Putting it into `grep`, you get something like this:

```
grep -Pi " (?=.{0,4}j)(?=.{0,4}a)(?=.{0,4}m)(?=.{0,4}e)(?=.{0,4}s).{5} " $file
```

Where `$file` is the file you want to `grep` through. Note that the `-P` flag requires GNU `grep`, and indicates that the pattern is a Perl-style regex (native `grep` regexes, even with `-E`, don't support lookaheads). The `-i` flag makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Use a look ahead for each letter that must appear within the word, 5 letters, all wrapped in word boundaries:

```
/\b(?=\w*j)(?=\w*a)(?=\w*m)(?=\w*e)(?=\w*s)\w{5}\b/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's hack up a tiny a grep program in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp, which underlines matches with carets:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/txr --lisp
(let ((regex (regex-compile (first *args*))))
  (whilet ((line (get-line)))
    (whenlet ((mlist (rra regex line))) ;; rra: regex ranges all
      (put-line line)
      (let ((carets (mkstring (to (find-max mlist)) #\space)))
        (mapdo (op mapdo (do set [carets @1] #\^) (range* (from @1) (to @1)))
               mlist)
        (put-line carets)))))
```

Run (upper case only; trivial to add lower case):

```
$ chmod a+x txgrep
$ ./txgrep '.....&.*J.*&.*A.*&.*M.*&.*E.*&.*S.*'
JAMES
JAMES
^^^^^
Hey there, JAMES; meet AMSEJAMS.
Hey there, JAMES; meet AMSEJAMS.
           ^^^^^       ^^^^^
SJAMSSEMASMSJEMSAMSESAMJESESJASMAS
SJAMSSEMASMSJEMSAMSESAMJESESJASMAS
            ^^^^^  ^^^^^
J
AJAMES
AJAMES
 ^^^^^
```

The regex simply denotes the set of strings which consist of five characters (`.....`) *AND* which contain a J (`.*J.*`) *AND* which similarly contain `A` and so on.

If we had repeated letters in a word and they all had to be present, like say `DOLLY`, it would be like this:

```
.....&.*D.*&.*O.*&.*L.*L.*&.*Y.*
```

The two `L`'s are covered by the `.*L.*L.*` which matches sets of strings containing at least two L-s. If we have at least two L-s, at least one D, at least one O, and at least one Y, and the length is five characters, we must have a jumbling of DOLLY.

Starting with `.....&.*J.*&.*A.*&.*M.*&.*E.*&.*S.*`, can we do some algebra to eliminate the exotic `&` operator? If we can algebraically reduce this to a manageable ordinary regex using only branching, catenation, and so on, we can use ordinary tools (and I mean no silly Perl extensions or anything: just old NFA regex).

A big conjunction immediately suggests De Morgan's Law (`A & B <==> ~(~A | ~B)`), which introduces negation. Can we then eliminate negation?

```
--> ~(~.....|~.*J.*|~.*A.*|~.*M.*|~.*E.*|~.*S.*)
```

Aha! Firstly `~.....` means "all strings not five characters long". That's easy: it's just the set containing: the empty string, all one-char-long strings, all two-char-long strings, .... NOT any five-char-long-strings, six char long strings and so on. We can express that without `~` easily:

```
(|.|..|...|....|......+)
```

Next, the set denoted by `~.*J.*` is just the set of strings that do not contain `J`. Easy with character classes! It's just `[^J]*`! Okay, so we can substitute this into our regex, and then all we have is one big negation out front:

```
~(|.|..|...|....|......+|[^J]*|[^A]*|[^M]*|[^E]*|[^S]*)
```

Let's check that this still works, by the way:

```
$ ./txgrep '~(|.|..|...|....|......+|[^J]*|[^A]*|[^M]*|[^E]*|[^S]*)'
JAMES
JAMES
^^^^^
Hey there, JAMES, meet AMSEJAMS.
Hey there, JAMES, meet AMSEJAMS.
           ^^^^^       ^^^^^
SJAMSSEMASMSJEMSAMSESAMJESESJASMAS
SJAMSSEMASMSJEMSAMSESAMJESESJASMAS
            ^^^^^  ^^^^^
J
AJAMES
AJAMES
 ^^^^^
```

Evidently, yes. Phew!

Where can we go from here?

Here is a crazy idea: suppose we allow ourselves to use word anchoring. Can we then find the lines containing password candidates using `grep -v`?

```
$ grep -v -E '\<(|.|..|...|....|......+|[^J]*|[^A]*|[^M]*|[^E]*|[^S]*)\>'
```

Unfortunately, this is as good as line anchoring: it works only when we have one word per line. It finds lines which are exactly `JAMES` or `MAJSE` and so on, but not anything else.

Of course, we know there is an ordinary, classic regex which matches the set we want, because the set is a finite permutation of a word; it's just that the obvious regex for that is way too darn large.

Or is it? Not really:

```
grep -E -i "JAMES|JAMSE|JAEMS|JAESM|JASME|JASEM|JMAES|JMASE|JMEAS|JMESA|JMSAE|JMSEA|JEAMS|JEASM|JEMAS|JEMSA|JESAM|JESMA|JSAME|JSAEM|JSMAE|JSMEA|JSEAM|JSEMA|AJMES|AJMSE|AJEMS|AJESM|AJSME|AJSEM|AMJES|AMJSE|AMEJS|AMESJ|AMSJE|AMSEJ|AEJMS|AEJSM|AEMJS|AEMSJ|AESJM|AESMJ|ASJME|ASJEM|ASMJE|ASMEJ|ASEJM|ASEMJ|MJAES|MJASE|MJEAS|MJESA|MJSAE|MJSEA|MAJES|MAJSE|MAEJS|MAESJ|MASJE|MASEJ|MEJAS|MEJSA|MEAJS|MEASJ|MESJA|MESAJ|MSJAE|MSJEA|MSAJE|MSAEJ|MSEJA|MSEAJ|EJAMS|EJASM|EJMAS|EJMSA|EJSAM|EJSMA|EAJMS|EAJSM|EAMJS|EAMSJ|EASJM|EASMJ|EMJAS|EMJSA|EMAJS|EMASJ|EMSJA|EMSAJ|ESJAM|ESJMA|ESAJM|ESAMJ|ESMJA|ESMAJ|SJAME|SJAEM|SJMAE|SJMEA|SJEAM|SJEMA|SAJME|SAJEM|SAMJE|SAMEJ|SAEJM|SAEMJ|SMJAE|SMJEA|SMAJE|SMAEJ|SMEJA|SMEAJ|SEJAM|SEJMA|SEAJM|SEAMJ|SEMJA|SEMAJ"
```

Case-insensitivity in `grep` (POSIX feature) takes care of much of the combinatorial explosion. Actually, without `-i`, all we have to do is replace each letter like `J` with the class `[Jj]`. That makes our pattern several times larger, but still reasonably manageable.

Starting with the above, we can fold in path compression. For instance, several jumblings of `JAMES`, six in fact, are matched by:

```
J(A(M(ES|SE)|E(MS|SM)|S(ME|EM)))
```

That is just a wee bit shorter than writing the six out in full:

```
JAMES|JAMSE|JAEMS|JAESM|JASME|JASEM
```

Now note that the part `M(ES|SE)|E(MS|SM)|S(ME|EM)` that generates those six suffix permutations can be factored out and applied against the prefix `JA` as well as `AJ`:

```
(AJ|JA)(M(ES|SE)|E(MS|SM)|S(ME|EM))
```

Look at that, we now have 12 matches. That's already 10% of the permutation space. There is a pattern here in that we have taken a particular permutation of the string, namely `JAMES` and split it (arbitrarily) into two pieces, namely `JA` and `MES`. Then we separately permute these pieces as `(AJ|JA)` (two ways) and `M(ES|SE)|E(MS|SM)|S(ME|EM)` (six ways), catenate them, and we have twelve.

Can't we just repeat this ten times and get all 120? Of course we can! There are ten ways of choosing two letters from a set of 5:

JA, JM, JE, JS, AM, AE, AS, ME, MS, ES

Each of these is matched in two ways, so twenty possibilities. Each of these is matched with six permutations of the remaining letters: 20 * 6 = 120. For each digraph we just write down one regex according to the above pattern which covers 12 out of the 120:

```
(AJ|JA)(M(ES|SE)|E(MS|SM)|S(ME|EM))
(JM|MJ)(A(ES|SE)|E(AS|SA)|S(EA|AE))
... eight more
```

Parenthesize these, those with '|' and you're done. The length is 10*35 + 9 = 359 characters.

This is substantially smaller than the original naive uncompressed regex which is 719 characters long.

In fact, 719 is 2*359 + 1. :)

**Supplementary approach:**

In TXR, there is a trie module that is used for some filtering features. What we can do is add all of the permutations of `JAMES` into a trie, and then convert that to a trie-compressed regex. However, the function to convert to regex doesn't exist. That's okay, we hack it up. The function transforms a trie to regex **abstract syntax**: a tree made of Lisp s-expressions. We can then compile that with `regex-compile`. The resulting object, as a side effect, has a printed representation rendered in regex character syntax (which is all we are ultimately after here: to see that form):

```
;; This produces S-exp based regex abstract syntax (AST) not
;; regex character syntax.
(defun trie-to-regex (trie)
  (typecase trie
    (null nil)
    (cons ^(compound ,(car trie) ,(trie-to-regex (cdr trie))))
    (hash (iflet ((pairs (hash-pairs trie)))
            (reduce-left (ret ^(or ,@1 ,@2))
                         (mapcar (aret ^(compound ,@1 ,(trie-to-regex @2)))
                                 pairs))))))
```

Okay, with that we can do:

```
$ txr -i trie-to-regex.tl
1> (defvar tr (make-trie))
tr
2> (perm "JAMES")
("JAMES" "JAMSE" "JAEMS" "JAESM" "JASME" "JASEM" "JMAES" "JMASE"
 "JMEAS" "JMESA" "JMSAE" "JMSEA" "JEAMS" "JEASM" "JEMAS" "JEMSA"
 "JESAM" "JESMA" "JSAME" "JSAEM" "JSMAE" "JSMEA" "JSEAM" "JSEMA"
 "AJMES" "AJMSE" "AJEMS" "AJESM" "AJSME" "AJSEM" "AMJES" "AMJSE"
 "AMEJS" "AMESJ" "AMSJE" "AMSEJ" "AEJMS" "AEJSM" "AEMJS" "AEMSJ"
 "AESJM" "AESMJ" "ASJME" "ASJEM" "ASMJE" "ASMEJ" "ASEJM" "ASEMJ"
 "MJAES" "MJASE" "MJEAS" "MJESA" "MJSAE" "MJSEA" "MAJES" "MAJSE"
 "MAEJS" "MAESJ" "MASJE" "MASEJ" "MEJAS" "MEJSA" "MEAJS" "MEASJ"
 "MESJA" "MESAJ" "MSJAE" "MSJEA" "MSAJE" "MSAEJ" "MSEJA" "MSEAJ"
 "EJAMS" "EJASM" "EJMAS" "EJMSA" "EJSAM" "EJSMA" "EAJMS" "EAJSM"
 "EAMJS" "EAMSJ" "EASJM" "EASMJ" "EMJAS" "EMJSA" "EMAJS" "EMASJ"
 "EMSJA" "EMSAJ" "ESJAM" "ESJMA" "ESAJM" "ESAMJ" "ESMJA" "ESMAJ"
 "SJAME" "SJAEM" "SJMAE" "SJMEA" "SJEAM" "SJEMA" "SAJME" "SAJEM"
 "SAMJE" "SAMEJ" "SAEJM" "SAEMJ" "SMJAE" "SMJEA" "SMAJE" "SMAEJ"
 "SMEJA" "SMEAJ" "SEJAM" "SEJMA" "SEAJM" "SEAMJ" "SEMJA" "SEMAJ")
3> (mapdo (op trie-add tr @1 t) (perm "JAMES")) ;; add above to trie
nil
4> (regex-compile (trie-to-regex tr)) ;; compile, get printed rep as side effect
#/A(E(J(MS|SM)|M(JS|SJ)|S(JM|MJ))|J(E(MS|SM)|M(ES|SE)|S(EM|ME))|M(E(JS|SJ)|J(ES|SE)|S(EJ|JE))|S(E(JM|MJ)|J(EM|ME)|M(EJ|JE)))|
E(A(J(MS|SM)|M(JS|SJ)|S(JM|MJ))|J(A(MS|SM)|M(AS|SA)|S(AM|MA))|M(A(JS|SJ)|J(AS|SA)|S(AJ|JA))|S(A(JM|MJ)|J(AM|MA)|M(AJ|JA)))|
J(A(E(MS|SM)|M(ES|SE)|S(EM|ME))|E(A(MS|SM)|M(AS|SA)|S(AM|MA))|M(A(ES|SE)|E(AS|SA)|S(AE|EA))|S(A(EM|ME)|E(AM|MA)|M(AE|EA)))|
M(A(E(JS|SJ)|J(ES|SE)|S(EJ|JE))|E(A(JS|SJ)|J(AS|SA)|S(AJ|JA))|J(A(ES|SE)|E(AS|SA)|S(AE|EA))|S(A(EJ|JE)|E(AJ|JA)|J(AE|EA)))|
S(A(E(JM|MJ)|J(EM|ME)|M(EJ|JE))|E(A(JM|MJ)|J(AM|MA)|M(AJ|JA))|J(A(EM|ME)|E(AM|MA)|M(AE|EA))|M(A(EJ|JE)|E(AJ|JA)|J(AE|EA)))/
```

The trie-compressed regex is large in terms of raw character count: more than 600.

Comment: TXR is *my* (self-assigned, seven-years-long and counting) homework.

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to answer: some code to generate a compressed regex by chunking an input string into trigraphs, which are spun into six permutations.

```
(defun break-trigraphs (string)
  (if (<= (length string) 3)
    string
    (mapcar (ret (list @1 (break-trigraphs (set-diff string @1))))
            (comb string 3))))

(defun trigraph-tree-to-regex (dtree)
  (typecase dtree
    (str (caseql (length dtree)
           (1 dtree)
           ((2 3) (reduce-right (ret ^(or ,@1 ,@2)) (perm dtree)))
           (t (error "bad trigraph tree"))))
    (cons
      (whenlet ((exprs (collect-each ((elem dtree))
                         ^(compound ,(trigraph-tree-to-regex (first elem))
                                    ,(trigraph-tree-to-regex (second elem))))))
        (reduce-right (ret ^(or ,@1 ,@2)) exprs)))))
```

REPL interaction:

```
$ txr -i trigraphs.tl 
1> (break-trigraphs "JAMES")
(("JAM" "ES") ("JAE" "MS") ("JAS" "ME") ("JME" "AS") ("JMS" "AE")
 ("JES" "AM") ("AMS" "JE") ("AES" "JM") ("MES" "JA"))
2> (trigraph-tree-to-regex *1)
(or (compound (or "JAM" (or "JMA" (or "AJM" (or "AMJ" (or "MJA" "MAJ")))))
     (or "ES" "SE"))
  (or (compound (or "JAE" (or "JEA" (or "AJE" (or "AEJ" (or "EJA" "EAJ")))))
       (or "MS" "SM"))
    (or (compound (or "JAS" (or "JSA" (or "AJS" (or "ASJ" (or "SJA" "SAJ")))))
         (or "ME" "EM"))
      (or (compound (or "JME" (or "JEM" (or "MJE" (or "MEJ" (or "EJM" "EMJ")))))
           (or "AS" "SA"))
        (or (compound (or "JMS" (or "JSM" (or "MJS" (or "MSJ" (or "SJM" "SMJ")))))
             (or "AE" "EA"))
          (or (compound (or "JES" (or "JSE" (or "EJS" (or "ESJ" (or "SJE" "SEJ")))))
               (or "AM" "MA"))
            (or (compound (or "AMS" (or "ASM" (or "MAS" (or "MSA" (or "SAM" "SMA")))))
                 (or "JE" "EJ"))
              (or (compound (or "AES" (or "ASE" (or "EAS" (or "ESA" (or "SAE" "SEA")))))
                   (or "JM" "MJ"))
                (compound (or "MES" (or "MSE" (or "EMS" (or "ESM" (or "SME" "SEM")))))
                 (or "JA" "AJ"))))))))))
3> (regex-compile *2)
#/(JAM|JMA|AJM|AMJ|MJA|MAJ)(ES|SE)|(JAE|JEA|AJE|AEJ|EJA|EAJ)(MS|SM)|(JAS|JSA|AJS|ASJ|SJA|SAJ)(ME|EM)|(JME|JEM|MJE|MEJ|EJM|EMJ)(AS|SA)|(JMS|JSM|MJS|MSJ|SJM|SMJ)(AE|EA)|(JES|JSE|EJS|ESJ|SJE|SEJ)(AM|MA)|(AMS|ASM|MAS|MSA|SAM|SMA)(JE|EJ)|(AES|ASE|EAS|ESA|SAE|SEA)(JM|MJ)|(MES|MSE|EMS|ESM|SME|SEM)(JA|AJ)/
```

Compressed down to 329 chars.